# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) when splitting line

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling, computer-science

```
with open("words_10percent.txt") as f:
   file_data = f.read()
word_frequency = {}
for line in file_data.split("\n"):
   word, frequency = line.split(",")
   word_frequency[word] = float(frequency)
```

In line 5 I get a value error when trying to split the line.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is this line: *word, frequency = line.split(",")*
Some line doesn't have *" , "*

try this:

```
with open("words_10percent.txt") as f:
   file_data = f.read()
word_frequency = {}
for line in file_data.split("\n"):
   if ',' not in line:
       print('line without ,:', line)
       continue
   word, frequency = line.split(",")
   word_frequency[word] = float(frequency)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is absolutely correct. There is no error. Check your text file again.

for demo purpose, I am adding four lines in 'words_10percent.txt' file as follows:

```
Ram, 50.55
class, 45.88
black, 35.99
data, 35.60
```

and I am getting the following output :

```
Ram
 50.55
class
 45.88
black 
 35.99
data
 35.60
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is generated by your data, you do not have in  at least one line the character `,`

you may check your last line, probably has a new line character `\n`